# Why does adding a function to prototype NOT over-ride original function definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

If I create a basic object and declare a function inside of it, then later use it's prototype property to over-ride the original function definition - nothing happens. The original function definition stays intact. I'd like a more seasoned JavaScript dev to explain why this doesn't work. I can't seem to find the right info searching google.

Here is my code for testing this assumption.

```
//Object definition
function Apple(type) {
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function() {
    console.log("Called getInfo() from inside Apple - original");
  }
}

//over write getInfo() -- dosn't work
Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  console.log("Apple getInfo called - prototype override");
};

a = new Apple();
a.getInfo();
```

Comment: The `getInfo()` in `Apple` will be declared when the constructor is run so you're not overriding it with prototype

Comment: So I would have to modify the prototype on the instance I create  ( in this case variable 'a' ) in order to override the function? Then if I want other objects to have this same override I'd have to create based off 'a' not 'Apple'??

Comment: When a property is accessed, the process of looking it up *starts* at the object itself, and only if the property is not found on the object is the prototype chain consulted.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `new Apple()`, then the original `this.getInfo = function` in your constructor is called, overriding what you have specified on the prototype.

Comment: The work on the prototype property is done after the definition of the function. Then later after that, the variable 'a' is declared. How is the mod to prototype completely ignored? Does that line ( 'Apple.prototype.getInfo' ) effectually do nothing?

Comment: @AndyJackson the prototype chain is only consulted if the property is not found directly on the target object.

Comment: @AndyJackson first you declare the constructor, then you declare what's on the prototype, then you create an instance which sets the original `getInfo` on the instance, and when you access it – the prototype chain is not consulted. You get the original `getInfo` function.

Comment: @AndyJackson: The work on the new instance, `this.getInfo = …` inside the constructor, is done when the instance is created - after the prototype is set.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the prototype works. Prototype methods don't "override" instance variables - to the contrary, the prototype chain is only consulted when a lookup fails amongst an object's own properties. *(i.e. if an object doesn't have a certain property, then a check is done on the object's prototype, and so on, propagating upwards the prototype chain until the first match is found.)*

In this case, `getInfo` exists on `a`, so no lookup is done on the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly the other way round. The method that is created on the instance itself (in the constructor) does override the one inherited from the prototype object. Notice that the order in which they appear in the source code has nothing to do with this.